# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Имеется приложение, которое хочу тестить на разных устройствах. На некоторых нормально запускается и работает, на других - вылетает при запуске с ошибкой:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.asus.antempire19, PID: 23268
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asus.antempire19/com.example.asus.antempire19.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.asus.antempire19.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.asus.antempire19-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2439)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.asus.antempire19.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.asus.antempire19-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.asus.antempire19.MainActivity
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 13 more
               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что работает на устройствах от Asus, а на остальных нет?

Comment: @rjhdby, нет, на Samsung работает, на китайских бюджетных - нет;
студия на ноутбуке Asus, поэтому путь такой

Comment: Причем, если передать apk-файл с устройства, на котором работает, на неработающее, то все запускается

Comment: Китайские телефоны с 32 битным Android?

Comment: В build.gradle по-моему multiDexEnabled = true попробуйте, погуглите про мультидекс, может поможет.

Comment: multiDex не помогает, даже если его в зависимости добавлять

Comment: А это не связано с этим *чюдесным* Instant Run в студии, попробуйте его отключить *Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy -->  Instant run*